# Does the successful tasks also gets reprocessed on an executor crash?

Tags: apache-spark

I am seeing about 3018 tasks failed for the job as about 4 executors died.
[image: Jobs View of Spark UI]

The Executors summary (as below in Spark UI) have a completely different statistics. Out of 3018, about 2994 properly completed. My question is,

1. Will they be re-tried again?
2. Is there a config to override/limit this?

[image: Executor View of Spark UI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After monitoring the job and manually validation the attempt counts event for successful tasks, realised

Will they be re-tried again?
    - Yes, even the successful tasks are retried.

Is there a config to override/limit this?
    - Did not find any config to override this behaviour.

If an executer (kubernetes pod) dies (like with an OOM or timeout), all the tasks, even if successfully completed are re-executed. One of the main reason is, the shuffle writes from the executers are lost with the executor itself!!!